# SocketTimeoutException in client Socket (in java)

Tags: java, sockets

I am developing a ServerSocket that delays a lot of time in processing a request, this cause an exception (SocketTimeoutException) in the client.
I have tried to increase the timeout and it works, but then the client doesn't receive anything from the server (without exceptions in both).

Server

```
    FileOutputStream parameters = new FileOutputStream(zipOutputPath);
    int len;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

    System.out.print("Receiving data...");

    while ((len = input.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        parameters.write(buffer, 0, len);
    }
    parameters.close();

    //This take a console output and send it to the client (sequentially). 
    //But some times the console can take several minutes to return a line (this is the problem)
    BufferedReader d = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new BufferedInputStream(Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command).getInputStream())));

    String lineOutput;
    while ((lineOutput = d.readLine()) != null) {
        if (!lineOutput.equals("")) {
            outPut.println(lineOutput);// outPut (PrintWriter) is the ServerSocket output
            outPut.flush();
        }
    }
```

Client

```
    System.out.print("Sending arguments...");

    int len;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    while ((len = zipFile.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        output.write(buffer, 0, len);
    }
    connection.shutdownOutput();// I do this because the server stays reading indefinitely, and I don't understand why, HELP ME WITH THIS TOO

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));

    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fileOutputPath);
    String line;

    //Here is where a SocketTimeOutException occur
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {            
            pw.println(line);
            pw.flush();            
    }
    pw.close();
    connection.close();
}
```

SORRY FOR MY ENGLISH

Comment: From the code that you provided it is NOT clear where the data on Server comes from. Is it receiving data from the client and then returning it in zipped form? The same applies to your Client - what is `zipFile`, `output`?

Comment: If the console takes a long time to return input, which can happen if the user goes out to lunch, you need to choose your socket timeout accordingly. It's too short,